# Linker cannot resolve symbol in template derivered override

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I have base class

```
template<typename T>
struct Counter {
    static int objects;

    virtual size_t getSize() = 0;
    ... //some other things
};
```

And derived class (in same file):

```
template <typename T, int N>
struct A : Counter<A<T,N>>{
    T data[N];
    size_t getSize() override {  //override don't make error
        return 100;  //100 for testing purpose only
    }
};
```

and later i use

```
A<int,10> a1;
```

When i'm trying to compile, i got linker error:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned int __thiscall  Counter<struct A<int,10> >::getSize(void)" (?getSize@?$Counter@U?$A@H$09@@@@UAEIXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Counter<struct A<int,10> >::Counter<struct A<int,10> >(void)" (??0?$Counter@U?$A@H$09@@@@QAE@XZ)
```

Comment: Does `//some other things` include an attempt to call `getSize` in the constructor of `Counter`? Because the code you posted builds just fine for me after I remove the syntax errors.

Comment: Yes , in constructor i'm tring to add to global static varible value returned by this function,
Counter() {
totalSize += getSize();
} and in destructor -= getSize()

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/ShQHqM), please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The linker error message reveals that you are trying to call getSize from Counter contructor. It is probably hidden in your "//some other things". Please add that code too because is most probably the root of the problem here.

For the moment I can say that you cannot call a pure virtual function of struct Counter in the struct Counter contructor.

Let's say a class/struct Y inherits from class/struct X, when you instantiate an object of type Y what happens is:

1. first X constructor is called
2. then Y constructor is called

When step 1) happens, the part of the object representing the class Y is not yet constructed, therefore none of its methods are meant to be executed yet.

Comment: You can in fact call a pure virtual function if it is defined. But that's not often what someone meant to do.